# Google Spreadsheet Formula

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Column B12 has a formula that adds the day of the week based on the date that is in Column C12. How do I create a formula so that in the next cell below, in B13, the formula leaves the cell empty until a date is entered into Column C.

[Sample of Spreadhseet with Formulas and Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRGJ7.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean in the whole of column C or in C13?

Comment: The whole Column C

Comment: @maymartin copy paste your current code? btw could you also paste your code in your answer so we can see what you are doing

Comment: My code in B12 is: =Text(C13,"ddd")

Comment: But if I paste that code to B13, and there's no date on C13, Sat still shows up, even though there's no date on C13.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the code you are looking for:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C13);"";TEXT(C13;"ddd"))
```

This code checks if the cell is empty with ISBLANK(cell)

If the cell is blank we do not show anything.
If the cell is not blank we will show the Day from the date that we get from cell C13.

Here is the formula in action.

[image: Example of output]

btw you can click and drag the formula over multiple cells to do the same thing for all cells on which you drag the formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need for your answer.

```
={IF(PRODUCT((C13:C1048576="")*TRUE())=0,"Blabla","")}
```

What this formula does is:

```
C13:C1048576=""
```

It first checks if all the cells in column C are empty. This will give true or false values.

```
*TRUE()
```

I then multiply this by the true value to change the values from true to 1 and false to 0.

```
PRODUCT(previous)=0
```

This checks if any of the cells is not empty, because this will cause a 0 in the array which will cause the product of all items in the array to be zero.

```
"Blabla"
```

This is the text you want to display.